# Intent extra doesn't return to previous fragment on onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I open a DatePickerFragment and select a new date but the date doesn't return with the intent extra to the previous fragment. I'm not sure why and a closer inspection using the debugger says
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [LObject;" when the method reaches that breakpoint on the code.
I'm following the BigNerdRanch Tutorial.

Here is my CrimeFragment

```
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

    public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID =
            "xxx.com.criminalintent.crime_id";
    public static final String DIALOG_DATE = "date";
    public static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UUID crimeId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

        mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);


    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int count, int after) {
                //Left blank
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count) {
                mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable c) {
                // Left blank
            }
        });
        mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        updateDate();
        mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager();
                DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment
                        .newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
                dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
                dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_DATE);


            }
        });

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
        mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //Set the crimes solved property.
                mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
    public void updateDate(){
        mDateButton.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
    }
    public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);

        CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){
            return;
        }
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_DATE){
            Date date = (Date)data
                    .getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
            mCrime.setDate(date);
            updateDate();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my DatePickerFragment

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;

/**
 * Created by xxx on 11/09/14.
 */
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_DATE =
            "xxx.com.criminalintent.date";

    private Date mDate;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        mDate = (Date)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATE);

        //Create a calendar to view year, month, day.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(mDate);

        //Assign the calendar date to local variables.
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);

        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datePicker);
        datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener(){
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
                    mDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                    //Update argument to preserve values on rotation.
                    getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
                }
        });


        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(
                        android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                            }
                        })
                .create();
    }

    /**
     * Static method to instanciate the DatePickerFragment
     * @param date
     * @return
     */
    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, date);

        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode){
        if(getTargetFragment() == null){
            return;
        }

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
        getTargetFragment()
                .onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, i);

    }


}
```

Comment: The first if-statement of your `onActivityResult()` method looks suspicious: `requestCode != Activity.RESULT_OK`. You probably meant to check `resultCode` there.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! It's always the little things that one doesn't notice.

Comment: I'll post is as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first if-statement of your `onActivityResult()` method looks suspicious: `requestCode != Activity.RESULT_OK`. You probably meant to check `resultCode` there.

Comment: As one of the authors of the Big Nerd Ranch guide, I can confirm that this is the correct answer :)

Comment: Ah, you mean to say it was a planted error that's part of the exercise? I'm sorry, I didn't realize. I'll delete the answer (and comment) if you feel it hurts your training program.

Comment: No, not at all. The error is not in our materials. Thanks for your consideration, though.

Comment: No, the error was only me. Too much and too long session made me blind. @lyricsboy Great book, on chapter 19 right now!